# How to apply regex for multiple values to create a new column in pandas?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a data frame like as shown below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({'s_id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
                'test':['Metformin','Glipizide','Gliclazide','Glibenclamide','Repaglinide','nateglinide','sitagliptin','linagliptin']})
```

I would like to create a new column called `op` based on values from the `test` column according to the criteria below

If the `test` value contains `*etformi*` pattern, then the `op` column should have a value `C1`.

If the `test` value contains the `gli*` pattern, then the `op` column should have a value `C2`

If the `test` value contains the `*nide` pattern, then the `op` column should have a value `C3`

If the `test` value contains the `*gliptin` pattern, then the `op` column should have a value `C4`

I tried the below but it doesn't work as expected and not sure how to merge them all together

```
df['test'].str.contains('metformi*', case=False, regex=True)
df['test'].str.contains(('gli*&&*ide'), case=False, regex=True)
df['test'].str.contains(('*nide'), case=False, regex=True)
df['test'].str.contains(('*gliptin'), case=False, regex=True)
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html), supplying a `condlist` and `choicelist`:

```
import numpy as np

condlist = [
    df['test'].str.contains('etformi', case=False, regex=True),
    df['test'].str.contains(('^gli.*ide$'), case=False, regex=True),
    df['test'].str.contains(('nide$'), case=False, regex=True),
    df['test'].str.contains(('gliptin$'), case=False, regex=True)
]

choicelist = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4']

df['op'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist)
```

[out]

```
   s_id           test  op
0     1      Metformin  C1
1     2      Glipizide  C2
2     3     Gliclazide  C2
3     4  Glibenclamide  C2
4     5    Repaglinide  C3
5     6    nateglinide  C3
6     7    sitagliptin  C4
7     8    linagliptin  C4
```

Comment: what would be assigned in `op` column if there is an entry in `test` column which doesn;t match any of the pattern.. It will be empty? Typing from mobile, so couldn't try

Comment: you can set a default in the `np.select` function. The default is `0`, but you might instead choose `default=np.nan` for example.

Comment: Is it kay to give multiple patterns like this for a single condition? `('Glimepiride|Tolbutamide|Glipizide|Glucotrol|Glyburide)`

Comment: Yeah should be fine